# Ionic doesn't work when I try to start a project in Windows 10

Tags: windows, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 5 with Node in Windows 10. I have a project created that works ok but when I try to create a new one using Ionic start after some time installing packages it gives me an error.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Ionic and Node but the problem continues.

I try to create the project using ionic start test

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path E:\trabajo\ionic\test\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'E:\trabajo\ionic\test\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-23T18_56_50_185Z-debug.log
Error

at new SubprocessError
(C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:40:23)
at ChildProcess.p.on
(C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:129:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit
(C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

Please, I need your help to continue developing with Ionic on my computer with Windows. How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The path to your node modules might be wrong or the permissions on your terminal.

Have you tried restarting, this might be needed for a node reinstall and when changing your path sometimes and running your cmd as administrator.

**I wanted to comment but i cant!**